# Accessing subclass method from superclass C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

So I know I can't actually access methods and attributes of a subclass from it's parent. 
But I have a program which stores Vehicles in an array (NOT arraylist - its homework).
The Vehicles then initialize into either Airplane, Boat, or a Car object derived from the Vehicle class. 
These subclasses have attributes which are unique, and I'm wondering as to how I could go about accessing these?

Here's some (simplified) relevant code:

```
Vehicle[] vehicles = new Vehicle[20];

vehicles[0] = new Airplane();

// Setting an attribute of the superclass
vehicles[0].Make = "Boeing";

// Set an attribute from the Airplane class
vehicles[0].Engine = "Jet"; //(obviously this doesn't work)
```

How could I go about working around this? I've researched for a couple hours but I'm stumped by this one problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: `((Airplane)vehicles[0]).Engine = "Jet"`?

Comment: You can use [Casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) to get that working.

Comment: you have to cast the object to its real type before you can access it. Which assumes you actually know the type. If you're just adding them to an array higgledy-piggledy then you're effectively throwing away that info when you turn it into a Vehicle. I'd guess it's unlikely you know what the original type was when you come to access it again. If you give us some context about what the overall aim of your code is, perhaps we can help you do it a better way.

Comment: Thank you!! And yes I know which element is of what type, so casting is the answer. My god its so simple

Comment: `(vehicles[0] as Airplane).Engine = "Jet";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access a reference through the type of its declaration. Because you declare the array to be of `Vehicle`, you cannot directly access subclass members.

To do so, initialize the object separately from the collection that contains it:

```
var jet = new Airplane();
jet.Make = "Boeing";
jet.Engine = "Jet";

vehicles[0] = jet;
```

Alternatively, use an object initializer:

```
vehicles[0] = new Airplane
{
    Make = "Boeing",
    Engine = "Jet"
};
```

It would be quite nonsensical to cast it back just after instantiating it, but you could do that as well:

```
vehicles[0] = new Airplane();
((Airplane)vehicles[0]).Make = "Boeing";
((Airplane)vehicles[0]).Engine = "Jet";
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting solved my issue:

```
((Airplane)vehicles[currentItem]).EngineType = "Jet";

// Rather than

vehicles[currentItem].EngineType = "Jet";
```

Comment: But if you know it's an`Airplane`, why do you treat it as a `Vehicle` there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but simply put casting is the solution for my problem. Before I posted I did not think to cast with objects. All this program does is store vehicles in a listbox. Is this wrong in some way?

Comment: Your code is assuming that the vehicle with the given index is an Airplane. If you know that, why do you use a Vehicle[] array and not an Airplane[] array? You generally use a collection of parent classes if you _don't_ know or care about the more derived type. Casting will throw an exception when `vehicles[currentItem]` isn't an Airplane.

Comment: I don't actually know the object in my code, since I am using a for loop to iterate through the vehicles[] array, then an if statement to test the typeof. Depending on the type it prints a message showing vehicle details, and these are private attributes of the subclasses. Thanks for your help though

Comment: But that's a design smell. If you want to have a collection of vehicles, you do so because you want to treat all vehicles the same. One solution could be to give the Vehicle base class a `public abstract void PrintDetails()`, which you can then implement in derived classes and call on the base class.

Comment: It's homework and we're required to use a single array of the base class Vehicle. Then we add the ability to instantiate new Boats, Cars and Airplanes into this array using textbox inputs. 
But your solution makes sense, and I've got the Display() method in each subclass, is this where the abstract keyword helps to save time to move that method into the base class?